# Bootstrap Responsive Menubar Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to develop a menubar for bootstrap in which the image logo be centerized instead to the usual left of the bar. But the problem is, the right links of the menu bar goes off screen. When I preview the page with a width greater than 2050 pixels, it looks fine.
[image: Greater than 2050px width - dreamweaver]

But when I have something smaller than that, the right links didn't respond to the window change and slid off the page.
[image: Size of 1780px width produces this result - dreamweaver]

Is there any way to fix this? I have been playing around with the `col-md-7` and the `col-md-offset-3` class of the `nav`. But it didn't fix the problem, just moves/resizes it around the top.

Here is the link to the snipp of the page. http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/rvGQz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIV with container class, that wraps your navigation, breaks the layout because of this class actually sets the width:

```
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
```

Remove container class from a DIV and that should do a magic for you.

Comment: Exactly, remove the `.container`, but you will also need to re-adjust your CSS: `.navbar .navbar-brand-centered { marrgin-left: -80px; }`.

Comment: Thank you so much! For the CSS, I just fixed it so it has `.navbar-brand-centered {left: 45%;}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you adjusted the media queries for each break point in the grid as you adjust your screen sizes?

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries